# Prove $\{1,2,4,8,16,32,\ldots\}$ is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Been working on this question for a while now and despite scouring my notes and the internet, i still haven't been able to come up with a good answer...

Prove that the set of numbers which are powers of 2 (i.e. $\{1,2,4,8,16,32,\ldots\}$) is a countably infinite set.

How would i go about proving this? could i use proof by induction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: *Hint.* Remind when we can say two sets have same cardinality. Can you find a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hint : The set of natural numbers is countably infinite, and so is this, because....?

Comment: Its a bit more obv if you take just {2,4,8..} and then add 1.

Comment: @EzWin.  Huh????

Comment: @William: I'm guessing that EzWin does not think of $0$ as a natural number, thus making the suggestion more "natural" as writing $\{2^n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$. Of course, $0$ *is* a natural number, so... :)

Answer (score 1):

***HINT***
$$2\rightarrow\color{red}1\\3\rightarrow\color{red}2\\\cdots\\n\rightarrow n-1$$
and
$$2=2^\color{red}1\\4=2^\color{red}2\\8=2^\color{red}3\\\cdots$$

You remember the definition? That's the first think to look.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach the problem.

1. [Any infinite subset of a countable set is countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)
2. Give an explicit bijection $f$ between the set $P$ of powers of $2$ and $\mathbb{N}$

$f(2^n)=n,\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ is such a bijection $f:P\to\mathbb{N}$

for any $p\in P$ we have by definition of $P$ that $p=2^n$

and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $2^n\in P$

Hope this helps